# How to cancel left or right rules with an !important tag?

Tags: html, css

I need to cancel a `left` rule in a CSS file and replace it with `margin-left`:

```
.aClass {
    left: 5px;
}
```

Rule to override:

```
.aClass {
    left: none !important;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

but `left: none` doesn't seem to do nothing and `left: 0` is repositioning the layer. So how to cancel the `left` rule? I shouldn't override the original rule, as it is a part of a plugin and it could be updated overriding the existing file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `left: auto !important;` instead of `left: none !important;`

Comment: So easy! Thanks. You're the first one, so you win :)

Comment: Reference for OP: [MDN left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) (see initial value)

Answer (score 5):

The default value for `left` is `auto`.

So something like this should do it:

```
left:auto !important;
```

Comment: No worries @ManoloSalsas :)

Answer (score 1):

use `left:0!important` tag

HTML

```
<div class="header">

<div class="ssd aClass">Try</div>

 </div>
```

CSS

```
.aClass {
    left: 15px;
    position:relative;
} 


.aClass {
    left: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 5px;}

.ssd{background:#c1c1c1; width:100px; height:100px}
```

Try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdCnM/)**

Comment: The layer is fixed positioned, so it won't work. I forgot to add this information in the question. Thanks anyway. Good option to other people.